# Nodejs: Data exchange between Server and Client

Tags: node.js, express

I'm developing a server app in Node.js. For better understanding I wrote a very light code just to better point my issue. This is the server-side:

**Server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 80;

var room = function(){
    this.users  = {};
    this.counter = 0;
}

app.get('/reg',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.params);
});

app.use('/recosh', express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));
app.listen(port, function(){console.log('ReCoSh Server Starts...\n');});
```

So inside the "public" directory I wrote the two following client-side files:

**room.js**

```
var room = {
    //notifica al server una nuova registrazione
    register: function(data){
        $.getJSON('/reg',data);
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="room.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            var register = function() {
                room.register({
                    "username": $("#username").val(),
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="step1">
            <input id="username">
            <button onclick="register()">register</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that by inserting an username and clicking on register, the code `console.log(req.params);` on the server just print `{}`. It seems the object is empty... If I try `console.log(req.params["username"])` it prints `undefined`.

Why this simple object is not visible by the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should change a little typo in your code into this

```
room.prototype.addUser = function(username){
    if(username){
        this.users[username] = username;
        this.counter++;
    }
}
```

changing `this.user[username]` to `this.users[username]`

Then change `app.use('/register'..` to `app.get('/register'..`, but I would recommend to use `post` method, but let's make work with little modifications and besides this you don't call the `register` function inside the callback. So you should do something like this:

```
app.get('/register',function(req,res){
    var data = {
        username: req.params['username']
    }
    room.addUser(data.username);
    console.log('user added\n');
});
```

On the other hand in your client side the input id is equal to `nickname` whereas you get the value by `username` id, so you should make this change as well:

`<input id="nickname">` to `<input id="username">`

Comment: Thanks for replying @Karlen. Regarding the `<input>` tag, I used "nickname" as id but in the script code in the `<head>` I wrote the function `register` in this way `room.register({ "username": $("#nickname").val() });}`. However I tried your suggestions but still not workign "user added" is not shown...

Comment: I see you have accepted the answer. Hope you succeed